# expected expression error in Min function c++

Tags: c++, opencv, min

Code:

```
for(int r = 1; r < H; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < W; c++){
        if (c == 0){
            dp[r][c] = min(dp[r-1][c+1], dp[r-1][c]);
        }
        else if (c == W-1){
            dp[r][c] = min(dp[r-1][c-1], dp[r-1][c]);
        }
        else {
            dp[r][c] = min({dp[r-1][c-1], dp[r-1][c], dp[r-1][c+1]});
        }
        dp[r][c] += (int)image.at<uchar>(r,c);
    }
}
```

This is my for loop where I am getting error.

[image]

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces inside parentheses works in cpp-11 or later version. First make sure cpp-11 is on in your IDE than run it.it will work.

Comment: I am using cpp-11. The same thing is working in another program but problem with this only.

Comment: Then problem is in somewhere else.not in this line.